# Google Analytics query report - PHP

Tags: php, yii, google-api, google-analytics-api, google-api-php-client

I'm trying to display the google analytics report in my web application which is to display top 10 pages and display browsers count, 
i am using this link [Hello Analytics Reporting API v4; PHP quickstart for service account](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/service-php) to develop it. I am getting below error,

> Error calling POST https://analyticsreporting.googleapis.com/v4/reports:batchGet: (401) Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential

CODE :

```
$analytics = initializeAnalytics();
$response = getReport($analytics);
printResults($response);


function initializeAnalytics()
{

    // Use the developers console and download your service account
    // credentials in JSON format. Place them in this directory or
    // change the key file location if necessary.
    $KEY_FILE_LOCATION = __DIR__ . '/preprod-b18917fe321f.json';

    // Create and configure a new client object.
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName("Hello Analytics Reporting");
    $client->setAuthConfig('{"web":{}}'); // provided the .json credentials
    $client->setScopes(['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly']);
    $analytics = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting($client);

    return $analytics;
}


function getReport($analytics) {

    // Replace with your view ID, for example XXXX.
    $VIEW_ID = "xxxxxx";

    // Create the DateRange object.
    $dateRange = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_DateRange();
    $dateRange->setStartDate("7daysAgo");
    $dateRange->setEndDate("today");

    // Create the Metrics object.
    $sessions = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Metric();
    $sessions->setExpression("ga:sessions");
    $sessions->setAlias("sessions");

    // Create the ReportRequest object.
    $request = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_ReportRequest();
    $request->setViewId($VIEW_ID);
    $request->setDateRanges($dateRange);
    $request->setMetrics(array($sessions));

    $body = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_GetReportsRequest();
    $body->setReportRequests( array( $request) );
    return $analytics->reports->batchGet( $body );
}


/**
 * Parses and prints the Analytics Reporting API V4 response.
 *
 * @param An Analytics Reporting API V4 response.
 */
function printResults($reports) {
    for ( $reportIndex = 0; $reportIndex < count( $reports ); $reportIndex++ ) {
        $report = $reports[ $reportIndex ];
        $header = $report->getColumnHeader();
        $dimensionHeaders = $header->getDimensions();
        $metricHeaders = $header->getMetricHeader()->getMetricHeaderEntries();
        $rows = $report->getData()->getRows();

        for ( $rowIndex = 0; $rowIndex < count($rows); $rowIndex++) {
            $row = $rows[ $rowIndex ];
            $dimensions = $row->getDimensions();
            $metrics = $row->getMetrics();
            for ($i = 0; $i < count($dimensionHeaders) && $i < count($dimensions); $i++) {
                print($dimensionHeaders[$i] . ": " . $dimensions[$i] . "\n");
            }

            for ($j = 0; $j < count($metrics); $j++) {
                $values = $metrics[$j]->getValues();
                for ($k = 0; $k < count($values); $k++) {
                    $entry = $metricHeaders[$k];
                    print($entry->getName() . ": " . $values[$k] . "\n");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Anyone please give me an idea to get rid of this error.

Comment: is the code prompting you for permissions to access the data?

Comment: @DaImTo No, it shows Error calling POST https://analyticsreporting.googleapis.com/v4/reports:batchGet: (401) Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Error calling POST https://analyticsreporting.googleapis.com/v4/reports:batchGet: (401) Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential

Means that you are not logged in you are not properly authenticating the client before running the code.

**posible issues with service accounts**

1. Check  `$client->setAuthConfig('{"web":{}}');` make sure this is the correct path to the json key file. should probably be `$KEY_FILE_LOCATION`
2. Make sure that you created service account credentials on Google Developer console and not something else this code will only work with a service account key file.
3. Make sure that you granted the service account access to your google analytics account.  Take the service account email address and add it as a user in Google analytics at the account level.

**Issue with json file location**

If you still have issues with the file you can put the location into an env

```
// Load the Google API PHP Client Library.
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
// Use the developers console and download your service account
// credentials in JSON format. Place the file in this directory or
// change the key file location if necessary.
putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS='.__DIR__.'/service-account.json');
/**
 * Gets the Google client refreshing auth if needed.
 * Documentation: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount
 * Initializes a client object.
 * @return A google client object.
 */
function getGoogleClient() {
    return getServiceAccountClient();
}
/**
 * Builds the Google client object.
 * Documentation: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/auth/service-accounts
 * Scopes will need to be changed depending upon the API's being accessed. 
 * array(Google_Service_Analytics::ANALYTICS_READONLY, Google_Service_Analytics::ANALYTICS)
 * List of Google Scopes: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes
 * @return A google client object.
 */
function getServiceAccountClient() {
    try {   
        // Create and configure a new client object.        
        $client = new Google_Client();
        $client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
        $client->addScope([YOUR SCOPES HERE]);
        return $client;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        print "An error occurred: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

[ServiceAccount.php](https://github.com/LindaLawton/Google-APIs-PHP-Samples/blob/master/Samples/Google%20Analytics%20Reporting%20API/v4/ServiceAccount.php)

Comment: Hello, i could not find the related code in this link https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/web-php

Comment: @US-1234 thats strange because i copied it from that page.  Five lines down in the first section of code.

Comment: @DalmTo sorry i am using this link https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/service-php

Comment: I have updated my answer to reflect that you are actually using a service account and not Oauth2 for authentication.

Comment: I have tried with key location, it shows me invalid json, so i tried to copy the json  $client->setAuthConfig('{"web":{}}');

Comment: If the json file is invalid go back to google developer console make sure its a service account json file and download it again.

Comment: Okay. Let me try.

Answer (score 0):

The error tells us that a user needs be logged in. You simply need to add the authentication part.

I suggest you to look at a sample [Google Oauth & Analytics v4 in PHP](https://gist.github.com/LindaLawton/1bdf5d6259c161c5bff35db0c01710da).

Comment: I really appreciate you linking him over to one of my samples. However hes following the official one he this may confuse him.